# Principal bundles of Lie groups in a short exact sequence

Tags: gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, quantum-anomalies

Consider a short exact sequence of Lie groups 
$$1 \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow L \rightarrow 1.$$
What can we say about the principal bundles with the above groups as structure groups (gauge groups)? In particular, how are the connections (gauge fields) of these three principal bundles related? Assume that the base space of the bundle is the $d$ dimensional space time $X$.

To give some context, I’m studying papers on anomalies in gauge theories, for example, see section 5 of [arxiv:1708.06806](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06806). A simpler example is when $G=U(1)$, $H=U(N)$, $L=PSU(N)=SU(N)/\mathbb{Z}_N$ discussed in [arxiv:1401.0740](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0740). In this context, I guess what I’m asking is how we can get a gauge field of $H$-bundle given the gauge fields of $G$- and $L$-bundles.

The ansatz 1.6 in these [lecture notes by Arun Debray](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/s18_higher_symmetries.pdf) mentions the above short exact sequence and the corresponding principal bundles but I don’t completely understand the description there.